# Plone/SQLAlchemy - How can I properly adapt an interface to a form for editing records in a backend database (using mapped class)?

Tags: sqlalchemy, schema, plone

I am trying to create a form for editing a record in a table.

Here is a brief sample of my Interface:

```
class ICalibration(Interface):
"""Interface class for Calibration
"""

    Calibration_ID = schema.Int(title=u"Calibration_ID",
                                required=False
                            )
    ...

    Calibration_Type = schema.Choice(title=u"Calibration Type",
                                     description=u"Type of Calibration",
                                     source=_calibrationTypes,
                                     required=True,
                           )

    ...
    Last_Calibration = schema.Datetime(title=u"Last Calibration",
                                   required=False,
                      )
...
```

Here is a brief sample of the ORMBase class:

```
@implementer(ICalibration)
class Calibration(ORMBase)

    __tablename__="Calibrations"

    Calibration_ID = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(),
                                       primary_key=True,
                                       autoincrement=True
                           )

    Calibration_Type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(),
                                         nullable=False
                                    )

    ...

    Last_Calibration = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.types.DateTime(),
                                         nullable=True,
                                    )

    ...
```

Here is what I have so for the form class:

```
class EditCalibration(form.SchemaForm):

    grok.name('edit-calibration')
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.context(ISiteRoot)

    schema = ICalibration

    id = None

    @memoize
    def getContent(self):
        self.id = self.request.get('id',None)
        if self.id:
            return session.query(Calibration).filter(Calibration.Calibration_ID == self.id).one()

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Submit')
    def handleOk(self, action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()
        #do something with data
    ....

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Cancel')
    def handleCancel(self, action):
        #redirect user
    ....
```

The values themselves do show up properly in their respective fields, but I am getting the error in the debug menu:

```
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', None, <InterfaceClass gpcl.calibration.calibration.ICalibration>)
```

How can I fix this problem so that it adapts correctly?

Also, for reference, I actually asked a [question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921612/zope-schema-plone-how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-datetime-field-in-an-updatewidg) that got an answer providing code for the Calibration and CalibrationForm classes.  Because the fields fill out fine, there is probably something I did wrong.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was.  I am using a DataGridField and there is some sort of javascript that it must be using, which it appears to "reload" the form or pass the form into z3c.validation (name?) when it gains focus or has a value added/edited, and when passing the form in, it doesn't maintain the id get parameter attached to the link.  This appears to have caused the 'Could not adapt' error I was getting.  I switched to using PublishTraverse instead of attaching a get parameter and the problem was solved.

So the question becomes how can I still use ?id=someId ?